# Quarkus Microprofile Rest Client ResponseExceptionMapper doesn't catch errors

Tags: java, quarkus, microprofile

I have a Rest Client in a Quarkus (1.8.1) service defined like this:

```
@RegisterRestClient
@Path("/")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public interface MyClient {
    @POST
    @Path("/{entity}")
    Response postEntity(@HeaderParam(value = "Authorization") String auth, 
            @PathParam("entity") String entity, Object payload) throws MyException;
}
```

And I have implemented `ResponseExceptionMapper` in the same package like this:

```
public class MyExceptionMapper implements ResponseExceptionMapper<MyException> {
    @Override
    public MyException toThrowable(Response r) {
        return new DynamicsException(r.getStatus() + " - " + r.readEntity(String.class));
    }
}
```

When I call the service it is currently returning a 404 error, and I expected the code in the `MyExceptionMapper` class to be called. However it doesn't and instead a `javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException` is thrown. The stack trace includes a call to the `DefaultResponseExceptionMapper`. It's seems that my mapper has not been registered.

How can I register my handler for invalid responses from calls to the service?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to register MyExceptionMapper as provider to the rest client with `@RegisterProvider(MyExceptionMapper.class)`.

```java
@RegisterRestClient
@RegisterProvider(MyExceptionMapper.class)
@Path("/")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public interface MyClient {
```

Answer (score 2):

Each implementation provides a default **ResponseExceptionMapper** implementation that will map and invoke a response to javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException when the response status code is >= 400. It has a priority of Integer.MAX_VALUE, and is meant to be
used as a fallback whenever an error is encountered. This mapper will be registered bydefault to all client interfaces, but this can be disabled by setting an MP Config property,
microprofile.rest.client.disable.default.mapper, to true.

`RestClientBuilder.newBuilder().property("microprofile.rest.client.disable.default.mapper",true)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
@ClientExceptionMapper
    static RuntimeException toException(Response response) {
        if (response.getStatus() > 200) {
            return new RuntimeException(response.readEntity(String.class));
        }
        return null;
    }
```